# Android How to remove the second title in my actionbar?

Tags: android, user-interface

i created an a custom toolbar to replace the default action bar of appcompat in android. but when i run the application i get two title, like in the picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPVE.png

i want only the title in the middle 
here the code:
Main.java

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Typeface mistral = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MISTRAL.TTF");
    TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    title.setText("Fyllo");
    title.setTypeface(mistral);


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id =item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.action_settings){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this is a menu option",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

MainMenu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.adams.fyllo.MainMenu">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:title="Services">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Toolbar Title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And for style, i am using AppTheme

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="NoTitleText">
    <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
</style>


</resources>
```

What can i do to remove this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove title with help of

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: when i do it in the emulator, it crash. i tried it on my phone, it is working. Do you know why?

Comment: Can i see crash report ?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.adams.fyllo.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:22)

Answer (score 1):

You have given titles two times either you want to **remove upper** one remove TextView which is inside **Toolbar** and setTitle of toolbar.

otherwise remove title from the **Toolbar**